# Convertir texto a fecha

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, materialize

Hola estoy trabajando con materialize css, y obviamente JS, quiero convertir una cadena cuyo formato es este: `Mar 12, 2018` quiero convertir eso a Date para poder almacenarlo en la BBDD como Date.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione con esto:

```
$this->formatoFecha = strtotime($this->edad);
```